# Java method writing to a file displaying odd behavior

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Question for the code gurus out there. I'm having a strange Java issue and maybe someone has some ideas. I have a method called logger() and all it does is write to the console and to a file.

```
 public static void logger(String UrlMessage) throws IOException {
    //
    // Write any errors out to a log file.
    //
    Date date = new Date();
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    String savestr = "C:\\DiversityTest\\Logs\\DiversityTestLog_" + formatter.format(date) + ".txt";
    File f = new File(savestr);

    PrintWriter out = null;
    if ( f.exists() && !f.isDirectory() ) {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(savestr), true));
        out.println(UrlMessage + "\n\r");
        out.close();
    } else {
        out = new PrintWriter(savestr);
        out.println(UrlMessage + "\n\r");
        out.close();
    }
        System.out.println(UrlMessage);
}
```

Pretty standard stuff.

Here is the code for SetProperty().

```
 public static void SetPropertyValue(String xpathValue, String myPropertyName) throws InterruptedException {

    // Instead of reading each property value from the file we're going to pass them in from the call in Main()

    // Start propotron
    //DiversityTest.propotronStart();

    // variable initialization
    BufferedReader br;
    String x;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\DiversityTest\\propotron.ini"));
        try {                   
            // We're going to loop through the input file one line at a time until we hit null <EOF>. 
            while ((x = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // parse the property name and value
                String tokens[] = null; 
                tokens = x.split(" ");
                String propertyName = tokens[0];
                String propertyValue = tokens[1];
                WebElement myElement;

                if (propertyName.contentEquals("appver")) {
                    WebElement droplist = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))  
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("applicationInput")));
                    droplist.click();

                    droplist = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))  
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("applicationName" + propertyValue)));
                    droplist.click();


                    myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("propertyFilter")));
                    //System.out.println("The text box contains " + myElement.getAttribute("value"));
                    if (!myElement.getAttribute("value").contains("bfm")) {
                        myElement.sendKeys("bfm");
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    propotronCheckBoxes();

                }

                if (propertyName.contentEquals(myPropertyName)) {
                    int attempts = 0;
                    while (attempts < 2) {
                        try {
                            myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                                    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpathValue)));
                            myElement.click();
                            break;
                        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                            attempts++;
                        }
                    }

                    // now the contents of the edit box have a different ID so get it and set it
                    attempts = 0;
                    while (attempts < 2) {
                        try {
                            myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                                    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(myPropertyName)));
                            myElement.clear();
                            myElement.sendKeys(propertyValue);
                            //System.out.println("We set " + myPropertyName);
                            break;
                        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                            attempts++;
                        }
                    }
                    DiversityTest.propotronSave();
                    DiversityTest.prcLogger("Property " + myPropertyName + " set to " + propertyValue);                                 
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);         
    //driver.quit();
}
```

Several other methods call logger(). One in particular is called SetPropertyValue(). Whenever SetPropertyValue() calls logger(), which of course writes the text out to the file on the PC. Here's the trick - on a coworkers PC it does not.

Now we have another method called GetGDSInfo() and it calls logger as well. This method logger works just fine on both PCs.

Both methods are declared public static void. Both methods are using Selenium webdriver.

I'm totally stumped.

One thing I did notice is am running 1.7.0_79 and she is running 1.8.0_0121.
I don't think that's it though because if it was both methods calling logger() would display the same behavior.

I am totally stumped. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Sounds like permissions aren't set. Wait a minute. Check the permissions on the Set propertyValue(). Is it throwing an Exception?

Comment: No exception is being thrown on either system.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it's the static declarations on the methods and/or another jar file on their system and not on mine that logger() is conflicting with.

Comment: Are you catching an exception somewhere, perhaps? Do you have a config set somewhere that would affect the way setPropertyValue() is being called? Was the directory not there when you first tried, and now it is? You should also probably be using Path instead of a string representation of the file path.

as an aside - good coding standard is to have your variables start lower case, so your argument to your logger should be `logger(String urlMessage)` instead of capital U

Comment: Put a print statement in this ans when called from setPropertyValue. You said it works with GetGDSInfo(), so the problem isn't her. Where is the setPropertyValue() code

Comment: I posted the additional code above.

Comment: The directory exists already. I will make Path change tomorrow as well as the name case change.

Comment: When things like this happen it's usually "some other problem". For example, you are saying that `SetPropertyValue` calls `logger`, but are you sure that on your co-worker's PC `SetPropertyValue` executes?

Comment: Yes, since it's Selenium I can see it go in and set the property values on the web page it's manipulating.